# Unable to scroll the likers page on Instagram using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, infinite-scroll

I am trying to build a web scraper that allows me to scrape the names of the 'likers' of a post on Instagram. I am able to automate the program to open instagram, log-in, go to a post, and open the 'Liked by (n) others' list.
[image: The step I could reach]

And then this is the code that follows, with the purpose of scraping the names of the likers. As only the top eleven persons who liked are shown at a time and the rest will show only after scrolling (which triggers an AJAX request, as I read from other people having similar problems), I wrote this code which is supposed to scrape the first eleven names, append them into a list, print it, and then scroll.

```
no_of_pagedowns = 5

while no_of_pagedowns:

    liker_list = []
    likers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("qyrsm")    

    for n in likers:

        #scrape the name of the likers
        liker = n.find_element_by_class_name("_4EzTm").get_attribute("textContent")
        liker_list.append(liker)

    no_of_pagedowns -= 1

    print(liker_list)

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div')

    #scrollcode
    driver.execute_script("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,660)")
```

It works and can return the names of the first eleven 'likers', but it doesn't scroll. I think the problem is that the code fails to focus on the right element, but I failed to find out which element I should focus in. It just gives the same 11 persons for five times. I also tried replacing the "scroll code" from

```
    driver.execute_script("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,660)")
```

to something like

```
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

or

```
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

where elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div')
```

I also tried this block of code:

```
no_of_pagedowns = 5

while no_of_pagedowns:

    liker_list = []
    likers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("qyrsm")    

    for n in likers:

        #scrape the name of the likers
        liker = n.find_element_by_class_name("_4EzTm").get_attribute("textContent")
        liker_list.append(liker)

    no_of_pagedowns -= 1

    print(liker_list)

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div').click()

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 660);")
```

I put a .click() after finding the element because I thought maybe a click is necessary to focus on the "liker list", and it actually made the scrolling happened. But then now another problem arises: it only scrolls down 1 liker more every loop, no matter what the value of y cood I put in, and at the 5th loop, it fails because it will click the 6th liker counting from the top, leading to the 6th liker's profile page.

I've been stuck in this scrolling problem for almost a week already. I googled and read so many people's similar problems and just couldn't find one that helps. I would really appreciate anyone who could help.

Comment: I have done something similar here, you can check it out here- https://github.com/Aqua-4/auto-insta/blob/master/insta_ops.py#L573

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for but here is what i tried in java when we were facing issues with scroll. The element wont automatically scroll into view and would scroll set number of objects so we wrote below code

```
   public static void scrollintoView(WebDriver driver, String Value) throws 
   InterruptedException {

    int totalAttempts = 30;

    while (totalAttempts > 0) { 

        totalAttempts = totalAttempts-1;


        try { // checks code for exceptions

            WebElement ele=  driver.findElement(By.xpath(Value));

            break; // if no exceptions breaks out of loop
        } 
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) { 

            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            executor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 300)");


          continue; // continues to loop if exception is found

        }}

    }
```

you try similar thing in python and the hard scroll can be set number of users you want to check at each scroll .
Let me know if this helps